# How to hide the controls in the VideoView in Android?

Tags: android, hide, android-videoview

I am using VideoView for playing video in my app but I would like to hide the controls in it. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: use framelayout and put videoview and other controls that you want to hide/show. (e.g. play-pause button in middle of the videoview, that hide/show when video is playing or in pause state).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To the Controls in the `VideoView`, we can set `MediaController` to `null`.

```
videoView.setMediaController(null)
```

Comment: It works but on some devices you will get the Null point exception: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.widget.VideoView.setMediaController(VideoView.java:270)

Comment: but in case of only hide forward button?

Comment: The later answer works better than the accepted answer here. Setting in invisible controller is more predictable behavior than setting null.

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
MediaController ctrl = new MediaController(context);
ctrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
videoView.setMediaController(ctrl);
```

Comment: Due to me using MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener to control the volume of my videoview i didnt have the luxury of setting .setMediaController(null), instead this soultion worked perfectly. thanks!

Comment: This is weird. if ctrl.setVisible(View.VISIBLE) after .GONE, it doesnt show